# Gaps in a line while trying to draw them with a mouse problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, draw

I have written a program to draw a sin function in a way it is not easy to explain, but really easy to see it, so this is the whole

```
import pygame
import math
import fractions

window = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))#, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.font.init()
running = True
w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 12)
myfont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 30)

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
wCol = (100, 100, 100)
yellow = (0, 0, 255)

#temp
last = [0, 0]
lastQ = 0
q = 0

unit = 50
radius = 100
xa = int(w/3)
ya1 = 0
ya2 = int(h)
xb1 = 0
xb2 = int(w)        
yb = int(h/2)
xc = int(xa - radius)
yc = int(yb)
subtraction = 2
rotCount = 0
points = []

def check4points(angleC, sinC):
    isInArr = False
    for i in points:
        if i[0] == angleC and i[1] == sinC:
            isInArr = True
        else:
            isInArr = False
    return(isInArr)

def draw():
    global points
    window.fill(white)
    #axis and units
    pygame.draw.line(window, black, (xa, ya1), (xa, ya2), 2) # OY
    pygame.draw.line(window, black, (xb1, yb), (xb2, yb), 2) # OX
    #x units
    deltaU = 0
    for i in range(xa, w, 50):
        pygame.draw.line(window, black, (i, (yb - 5)), (i, (yb + 5)), 1)
        text = myfont.render(str(fractions.Fraction(deltaU).limit_denominator()) + "PI", 1, black)
        window.blit(text, (i - 15, yb + 5))
        deltaU += 1/6
    deltaU = 0
    for i in range(xa, 0, -50):
        pygame.draw.line(window, black, (i, (yb - 5)), (i, (yb + 5)), 1)
        text = myfont.render(str(fractions.Fraction(deltaU).limit_denominator()) + "PI", 1, black)
        window.blit(text, ((i) - 15, yb + 5))
        deltaU -= 1/6
    #y units
    deltaU = 0
    for i in range(yb, h, 50):
        pygame.draw.line(window, black, ((xa - 5), i), ((xa + 5), i), 1)
        text = myfont.render(str(deltaU), 1, black)
        window.blit(text, (xa + 10, i - 10))
        deltaU -= 0.5
    deltaU = 0
    for i in range(yb, 0, -50):
        pygame.draw.line(window, black, ((xa - 5), i), ((xa + 5), i), 1)
        text = myfont.render(str(deltaU), 1, black)
        window.blit(text, (xa + 10, i - 10))
        deltaU += 0.5
    text1 = myfont2.render("Kąt: " + str(angle), 2, black)
    text2 = myfont2.render("Sinus kąta: " + str(sinFinal), 2, black)
    text3 = myfont2.render("R - Reset", 2, black)
    window.blit(text1, (50, 100))
    window.blit(text2, (50, 130))
    window.blit(text3, (w*0.9, h*0.9))

    #circle thingy
    pygame.draw.circle(window, black, (xc, yc), radius, 2)
    pygame.draw.line(window, wCol, (xa - (2*unit), yb), satelliteCenter, 3)
    #pygame.draw.line(window, wCol, (mouse_xPos, mouse_yPos), (mouse_xPos, yb), 2)
    #pygame.draw.line(window, wCol, (mouse_xPos, mouse_yPos), (xa, mouse_yPos), 2)


    #point/sin graph
    pygame.draw.line(window, yellow, satelliteCenter, (satelliteCenter[0], yb), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(window, wCol, satelliteCenter, (w, satelliteCenter[1]), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(window, wCol, (0, satelliteCenter[1]), satelliteCenter, 2)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, red, satelliteCenter, 6)

    sinC = int(yb - (sinFinal * 100))
    angleC = (int(angle*(5/9)*3) + xa)

    point = [angleC, sinC]

    if check4points(angleC, sinC) == False:
        points.append(point)

    for i in range(len(points) - 1):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, red, (points[i][0], points[i][1]), 6, 0)

    pygame.draw.line(window, yellow, (angleC, sinC), (angleC, yb), 2)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
                quit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rotCount -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rotCount += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                points = []
                rotCount = 0

    mouse_xPos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
    mouse_yPos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

    satelliteCenter = (xc+radius, yb)
    vector = (mouse_xPos-xc, mouse_yPos-yb)
    distance = (vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)**0.5

    if distance > 0:
        scalar = radius/distance
        satelliteCenter = (int(round(xc + vector[0]*scalar)),
                           int(round(yb + vector[1]*scalar)) )

    if q == 1 and lastQ == 4:    
        rotCount += 1
    elif q == 4 and lastQ == 1:
        rotCount -= 1

    lastQ = q


    last = satelliteCenter

    xrel = (mouse_xPos - xa)/50
    yrel = -(mouse_yPos - yb)/50
    xcircle = -2

    x = xrel - xcircle
    y = yrel
    hypotenuse = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

    sin = y/hypotenuse
    angle = math.degrees(math.asin(sin))
    if x >= 0 and y > 0:
        angle = angle + (rotCount*360)
        q = 1
    elif x > 0 and y <= 0:
        angle = angle + 360 + (rotCount*360)
        q = 4
    elif x <= 0 and y < 0:
        angle = 180 - angle + (rotCount*360)
        q = 3
    elif x < 0 and y >= 0:
        angle = 180 - angle + (rotCount*360)
        q = 2

    sinFinal = math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have tried to subtract x coordinate of last drawn point and x coordinate of currently drawn one and check if it is greater than a given number (eg. 2 pixels). It seems to fail and is really non-efficient

These are the lines drawing the points:

```
    sinC = int(yb - (sinFinal * 100))
    angleC = (int(angle*(5/9)*3) + xa)

    point = [angleC, sinC]

    if check4points(angleC, sinC) == False:
        points.append(point)

    for i in range(len(points) - 1):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, red, (points[i][0], points[i][1]), 6, 0)

    pygame.draw.line(window, yellow, (angleC, sinC), (angleC, yb), 2)
```

If you could, please, tell me how I could make a perception of a smooth line.
Thanks in advance :)

BTW Don't judge me for my spaghetti code, I am just a beginner :D

Comment: First off, from a cursory scroll through your code, your `check4points` method doesn't work correctly. It will only return `True` if it matches the last point in the array.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey This method is just to enhance the performance. I am checking if the last two points are not different - when they are, then the cursor stays in one place, so there is no point in drawing a point with the same coordinates. And I think I dont have to check every time for the whole array, the last point compared to the currently drawn is enough, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) instead of `int`:

```py
sinC   = round(yb - (sinFinal * 100))
angleC = round(angle*(5/9)*3 + xa)
```

To find existing points in the list (`points`) it is sufficient to find [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) point with the same *x* coordinate:

```py
any([x for x in points if x==point[0]])
```

Sort ([`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)) the list of points, after a new point was added:

```py
point = [angleC, sinC]
if not any([x for x in points if x==point[0]]):
    points.append(point)
    points = sorted(points, key = lambda p : p[0])
```

When the curve is drawn, then calculate the *x*-distance of a point to its successor and predecessor:

```py
dist_p = 0 if i==0 else points[i][0]-points[i-1][0]
dist_s = 0 if i>len(points)-2 else points[i+1][0]-points[i][0]
```

Draw a point, when the distance to the successor and predecessor is acceeded by a certain `threshold` and draw a line else:

[image]

```py
sinC   = round(yb - (sinFinal * 100))
angleC = round(angle*(5/9)*3 + xa)

point = [angleC, sinC]
if not any([x for x in points if x==point[0]]):
    points.append(point)
    points = sorted(points, key = lambda p : p[0])

threshold = 10
for i in range(len(points)):
    dist_p = 0 if i==0 else points[i][0]-points[i-1][0]
    dist_s = 0 if i>len(points)-2 else points[i+1][0]-points[i][0]
    if dist_p > threshold and dist_s > threshold: 
        pygame.draw.circle(window, red, points[i], 6, 0)
    elif 0 < dist_p < threshold:
        pygame.draw.line(window, red, points[i-1], points[i], 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however there are still gaps while QUICKLY moving a mouse and I still cant figure it out. If you could help me with filling those gaps i would be reeeeeally greatful

Comment: @IgorSmorąg Of course, there are gaps, because the are no points calculated for this positions. You've to calculate points for the gaps and insert them into the list.